# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problema na validação do `Select`, seria uma validação de login e estou com problema no *Select* .

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function select * from
> usuario where email='() in C:\WEB\cadastro\valida.php:4 Stack trace:
> #0 {main} thrown in C:\WEB\cadastro\valida.php on line 4
> ```

segue abaixo o select:

```
$sql= mysqli_query ($conexao,"select * from usuario where email='"($_POST['email'])."' and senha='".($_POST['senha_usu'])."' limit 1") or die("Erro");
```

Comment: Ele ta usando myslqli, não vai mudar, acho que o problema está aqui,  email='"($_POST['email'])."'  , ta concatenado errado, deixa assim:  email='".$_POST['email']."'

Comment: Você só esqueceu de um ponto

Answer (score 5):

É problema na concatenação (falta o ponto "."):

```
$sql= mysqli_query ($conexao,"select * from usuario where email='."($_POST['email'])."' and senha='".($_POST['senha_usu'])."' limit 1") or die("Erro");
```